# How to diagnose slow HTTPS requests from Web API

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, iis-6, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Web API (ASP.NET Core 3.0, IIS 6.2) on Windows Server 2012 R2. When it's making an HTTPS request to an external SOAP API, I get a responce with code 500 after 20 seconds. My API wrote in a log:

> The operation timed out

Tail of an exception stack trace:

> at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

I repeat my API's request from the same server to external one by SoapUI. It's successfull after 2-3 seconds. Also my Web API works from my another server.

Unfortunatelly, I don't know how to get a reason of the problem. Can you give me any idea, please?

Comment: What method do you use to call the service in the `WebAPI` project, and directly construct the HTTP request? I suggest you use a proxy class or channel factory to call the service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client  In addition, please post the configuration of the WCF server. I will try my best to provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I just updated nuget packages `System.ServiceModel.*` from 4.4.0 and WCF requests work appropriately now.

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2368